# Removing a specific symbol from an SO file?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, linux-device-driver

I tried to remove symbol using:

```
objcopy -v -I elf32-little -N <function> main_lib.so new_lib.so
```

On which it says:

```
copy from `main_lib.so' [elf32-little] to `new_lib.so' [elf32-little]
```

There is no change between the two files, and the function is *not* removed.

I used to following commands to get the list of functions and format:

```
readelf -Ws main_lib.so > main_functions.txt
file main_lib.so
```

File command says:

```
main_lib.so: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[md5/uuid]=..., stripped
```